# How to get terms from term store, just the terms not the xml?

Tags: infopath

I am queriyng the term store using the _vti_bin/TaxonomyClientService.asmx?WSDL however I am not getting the terms back instead i get na xml reply...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><TermStore><T a9="4e127517-f627-4587-9e2d-12ebc01d1gfa" a21="false" a61="0"><LS><TL a32="Engineer" a31="true" /></LS><DS /><TMS><TM a24="3831295d1-c68d-4c6d-b587-48ffaf1aecc9" a12="Job Title" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="4e127517-f627-4587-9e2d-12ebc01d1eaa" /></TMS></T><T a9="722ef6c5-5764-4a8c-ab2a-8249c8af9927" a21="false" a61="0"><LS><TL a32="Professor" a31="true" /></LS><DS /><TMS><TM a24="3832395d1-c68d-4c6d-b587-48ddaf1aecc9" a12="Job Title" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="722ef6c5-5764-4a8c-ab2a-8249c8af9927" /></TMS></T></TermStore>
```

I just what the atual terms... is there a simple way to do this or does it require to edit the schema?

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect to get back from a web service? You can parse the XML or use XSLT.

Term stores are hierarchical and can't be returned with a flat structure.

I'd recommend reading up on web services, what they are, and what they do: [Web Services with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx).

If you want to work with the terms as objects instead of XML server side without calling the web service, you can use the classes in the [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy` Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: I have 3 days experience with sharepoint and infopath. I am quite familiar with WS. I have no idea how infopath is suposed to work. I am using infopath to generate the connection, i would rather be doing this with code, but I have no idea where the form/page code is supposed to be stored. I am basing on this tutorial http://m4sh3d.blogspot.pt/2013/08/infopath-2010-populating-dropdown-with.html and http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/sharepoint-2010-display-sharepoint-groups-in-an-infopath-form-drop-down-list-box/

Comment: http://johanolivier.blogspot.com/2010/08/infopath-2010-development-part-1-add.html No worries. Everyone starts somewhere.